# Commutation relation and eigenvectors of infinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, quantum-mechanics, eigenvector

I'm given the Matrix $A$ and $A^T$:

$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0  & \dots \\
    0 & 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & \dots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & \dots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix},
\ A^T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & \dots \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots \\
    0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & \dots \\
    0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & \dots \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$

First I'm asked to find the commutation relation $[A,A^T]$, which I calculated to be the Identity matrix.

Then I'm asked to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors or $A^TA$, and I'm stuck. From the first part I found:

$
A^TA = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & \dots \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots \\
    0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & \dots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & \dots\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$

I'm not sure how to go about this with an infinite matrix. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: if $A^T A$ has only diagonal elements there is nothing left to calculate if you seek eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I really let my brain go to rot over winter break. It took me too long to realize how simple this was.